# Q:What does '-' mean in bash scripting?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

```
if [ -n "${GITHUB_WORKFLOW-}" ];then
```

In the above code, this symbol‘-’ has no effect on the result. Why does this symbol‘-’ exist here?What else does it do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See *Parameter Expansion* in `man bash`. It uses an empty default value if the variable is unset.

> `${parameter:-word}`
>                Use Default Values.  If `parameter` is unset or null, the expansion  of  `word`
>                 is substituted.  Otherwise, the value of `parameter` is substituted.

and the paragraph above

> Omitting the colon results
>          in a test only for a parameter that is unset

Comment: Yes, and "word" is empty.